# jQuery DatePicker - How do I show today's month instead of the selected dated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

So I've been looking everywhere for an answer. Including jQuery's datepicker API website and I can't seem to find a suitable answer.

This is what I would like to happen. When the text field is pressed and the datepicker pops up, I would like the calendar month to show this month, rather than defaulting to any previously selected date.

I still want to be able to select next and previous on the months. So setting minDate is not an option.

So for example, a user has previously selected 03/03/2013. The user then clicks the textbox, which pops up the date picker again, the month displayed is today's month rather than March. However, 03/03/2013 is still selected.

Thanks!

Code is very vanilla...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".datePickerShowToday").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            buttonText: 'Click here to select a date',
            onSelect: function () {

            }
        });
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" id="NotificationDate" class="datePickerShowToday" />
```

Comment: so where is your code? post it here

Comment: thanks for getting back. Code now been added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the `$.datepicker._gotoToday` function [this is what the datepicker uses for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd>]. However, the widget doesn't provide an `open` event (it has `beforeShow` but that won't work in your case as it only runs before the widget is drawn). You can simulate this by using `.focus` on the input field and only binding one handler at a time (since keeping focus on the datepicker itself also triggers `focus`):

```
$( ".datePickerShowToday" ).datepicker({
    onClose: function() {
        $( ".datePickerShowToday" ).one("focus", function() {
            $.datepicker._gotoToday(this);
        });
    }
});
$( ".datePickerShowToday" ).one("focus", function() {
    $.datepicker._gotoToday(this);
});
```

Here's a fiddle with the above: http://jsfiddle.net/4vskg74t/

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! Just what I was after. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.datePickerShowToday').datepicker();   

    $(".datePickerShowToday").click(function(){   
        $('.datePickerShowToday').datepicker('setDate', null);
    });

});
```

Comment: This will lose the current value.